Go: test fails when expected value is the same as got value
I'm learning to test http endpoints in Go with the httptest library and my test is failingeven though by the result it should pass.
The function being tested:
func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Fprintln(w, t.YearDay())
}

The test:
func TestTestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(testHandler))
    resp, err := http.Get(server.URL)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("expected 200 but got %d", resp.StatusCode)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    tme := time.Now()
    expected := strconv.Itoa(tme.YearDay())
    b, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
    if string(b) != expected {
        t.Errorf("expected %s but got %s", expected, string(b))
    }
}

The output:
=== RUN   TestTestHandler
    testing_http_test.go:31: expected 191 but got 191
--- FAIL: TestTestHandler (0.00s)

i did check that both values are of the same type and they're both strings, i also tried with hardcoded strings but the test fails either way, so it must be something wrong with the way i'm making the test, though it only gives an error when comparing string(b) != expected even though they're the same value and type.
Anyone got a clue?

You're not accounting for the newline added by fmt.Fprintln. To make these things visible run both expected and actual value through fmt.Sprintf("%q").

I can't reproduce it with expected := strconv.Itoa(191) and b := []byte{49, 57, 49}. Can you try printing the exact bytes of each string?

@Peter is right, it's the newline, i trimmed it and it works now, i also removed the trim and just called Fprint instead of Fprintln which solved it as well

The answer is trailing whitespace, so be sure to trim what you get from the server if you get the same issue:
got := strings.TrimSpace(string(b))
if actual != expected {
    t.Errorf("expected %s but got %s", expected, got)
}

